# python regression: predicting model with new data

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, prediction

I am trying to use new data to predict new outcomes, however, I am dealing with the following error:

> ValueError: feature_names mismatch: ['time', 'x', 'y'] ['f0', 'f1',
> 'f2'] expected x, time, y in input data training data did not have the
> following fields: f0, f1, f2

I can't understand why, since I have 3 predictors and I am using exactly 3 values in my array.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import xgboost as xgb
import datetime
import seaborn as sns
from numpy import asarray

data=[[1, 1,2 ,5],
        [2, 5,5,6],
        [3, 4,6,6]
        ,[5, 6,5,6],
        [7,9,9,7],
        [8, 7,9,4]
        ,[9, 2,3,8],
        [2, 5,1,9],
        [2,2,10,9]
        ,[3, 8,2,8],
        [6, 5,4,10],
        [6, 8,5 ,10]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['time','x','y','target'])
xgb_reg=xgb.XGBRegressor( n_estimators= 30, max_depth=8, eta= 0.1, colsample_bytree= 0.4, subsample= 0.4) #(n_estimators=250, max_depth=15, eta=0.1, subsample=0.4, colsample_bytree=0.4)
y = (df.target)
X=df.drop(['target'], axis = 1)
print('========1=============')
model=xgb_reg.fit(X,y)
prediction=model.predict(X)
new_data=[[10,10,10]]
new_data_asarray=asarray(new_data)
pred=model.predict(new_data_asarray)
print(pred)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because your model is expecting a pandas dataframe as input.

Simply convert your X dataframe to a numpy array before training as shown below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xgboost as xgb


data = [
    [1, 1, 2, 5],
    [2, 5, 5, 6],
    [3, 4, 6, 6],
    [5, 6, 5, 6],
    [7, 9, 9, 7],
    [8, 7, 9, 4],
    [9, 2, 3, 8],
    [2, 5, 1, 9],
    [2, 2, 10, 9],
    [3, 8, 2, 8],
    [6, 5, 4, 10],
    [6, 8, 5, 10],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["time", "x", "y", "target"])
xgb_reg = xgb.XGBRegressor(
    n_estimators=30, max_depth=8, eta=0.1, colsample_bytree=0.4, subsample=0.4
)  # (n_estimators=250, max_depth=15, eta=0.1, subsample=0.4, colsample_bytree=0.4)
y = df.target
X = df.drop(["target"], axis=1)

X = X.to_numpy()

print("========1=============")
model = xgb_reg.fit(X, y)
prediction = model.predict(X)
new_data = [[10, 10, 10]]
new_data_asarray = np.asarray(new_data)
pred = model.predict(new_data_asarray)
print(pred)
```

Answer (score 1):

xgb expects same *type* of data for training and test. Since you used a pandas dataframe for training but gave a numpy array in prediction, it gives an error. (further, it tries to make a dataframe out of that array with default column names `f*` as the error suggests).

Therefore a fix is to convert the array used in prediction to a frame with the column names taken from the training `X` dataframe:

```
new_data = [[10,10,10]]
new_data_as_frame = pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns=X.columns)
pred = model.predict(new_data_as_frame)
```

Comment: thank you, but now there is one more issue. let's say I want to predict the outcome for different values of 'time', from 20 to 30, the following lines for i in range(20,30):
        new_data=[[i,10,10]]
        new_df=pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns=X.columns)
        pred=model.predict(new_df)
        print(pred)
print out the same exact value. Isn't it strange ?

Comment: @d8a988 That's a machine learning question. You have 12 training data samples and it seems it's not enough for the model to distinguish between different `time` features *once* the other 2 are fixed at 10.

Comment: i.e., this is a tree based model with 30 sequential trees in it. It seems `time` feature doesn't play an important role for branching in the trees when given a fixed pair of `[10, 10]` of `x, y`, which leads to the same path regardless of `time`.

Comment: but then what would be the best strategy in order to make the other two variables change according to 'time' ?

Comment: More data? Different parameters? Different algorithm?

Comment: if for instance I have more data, would you consider a good strategy the one of iterating through the 'time' variable as I did, and use the average of the rest of the variable for every iteration? Or you would recommend something else ?

Comment: not sure I follow. In prediction time, you're free to use any values you want. Model will have been already trained and won't really know how you supply the values in test time. If you mean supplying 2 features in total by *the average of the rest of the variable*, that's not possible; training and test features should have the same cardinality.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234649/discussion-between-d8a988-and-mustafa-aydin).

Answer (score 1):

When I provide input as a dataframe, with specified column names, it works.

```py
model = xgb_reg.fit(X, y)
prediction = model.predict(X)
new_data = [[10, 10, 10]]
new_data = pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns=['time', 'x', 'y'])
pred = model.predict(new_data)
print(pred)  # [6.3624153]
```

Comment: if I change the 'time' input to any number, the outcome is still the one you predicted. How so? isn't it strange?

Comment: Not exactly. I did a for loop, `for i in range(100)` to replace `time` column and perform 100 predictions. I got [6.298867]
[6.298867]
[6.9000916]
[6.8208203]
[6.8208203]
[7.0572853]
[7.0842357] ....